# Como calcular amplitude de cada classe em R?

Tags: r, diff, range

tenho a seguinte variável em R

```
    set.seed(7)
valor <- round(runif(35, min=30, max=100), 2)
```

Quero calcular a amplitude (valor maximo - valor mínimo) para cada classe dos meus dados.
Para calcular a amplitude máxima(de todas as classes), eu fiz: `diff(range(valor))`

No entanto, não sei como fazer para cada uma das classes, pelo método de Sturges(nclass.Sturges) eu obtive q tenho 7 classes.

Answer (score 1):

Por definição, as classes de um histograma construído através do método de Sturges terão sempre a mesma amplitude. Portanto, basta tomar a amplitude total da amostra, dada por  `diff(range(valor))`, e dividi-la pelo número de classes, dado por `grDevices::nclass.Sturges(valor)`. Assim, temos

```
set.seed(7)
valor <- round(runif(35, min=30, max=100), 2)
diff(range(valor))/grDevices::nclass.Sturges(valor)
9.88
```